# The population proportion parameter is an estimator?

Tags: statistics

I had a test exam in which the question was the following:

The population proportion parameter is:

a) an estimator with variance $p(1-p)$

b) none of the others

c) an estimator with standard error equal to $\sqrt{p/n}$

d) an unbiased estimator

I selected b), because in all the other option we assume that the population proportion is an estimator.

Turns out the answer was d).

If someone knows why I would be glad to know.

Thanks.

Comment: I think what is meant is this: If $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a sequence of Bernoulli with parameter $p$ distributed random variables, then $\frac{X_1+\dots+X_n}{n}$ is an unbiased estimator of $p$. (This is true even without any assumption on the dependency structure of the $X_n$‘s by linearity of expectation). If we assume independence, the variance is $\frac{p (1-p)}n$, which matches neither a) nor c).

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are not estimators.  Parameters are **fixed but unknown** quantities.  An estimator is a statistic, which is in turn a function of the sample that does not depend on any unknown parameters.  It is incorrect to say that a population parameter is an estimator, because if you knew what the population parameter was, you would not need to sample any data to estimate it.  You already know it.

The way this question is worded is misleading at best.  It also seems like there's more to the question than what is stated.  The full and exact text of the question should be included so as to avoid any misinterpretation.

---

A correct statement would be:

> The **sample proportion** is an unbiased estimator **of the population proportion**.

The first part clarifies that we are calculating a statistic, and implies that the sampling occurs at random.  The second part clarifies what parameter the estimator is estimating--the population proportion.  If you say something is an estimator, you also have to say what it is estimating.  Assuming what you provided is the complete statement of the question, whoever wrote it does not understand statistics and is not qualified to teach statistics.